# How does Maven integrate with TAR?

Tags: maven, gzip, integration, tar

I want to know how Maven integrates with TAR : Does it simply call out to your OS' native version of TAR, or does it have an internally packaged version in its "/lib" Jars somewhere, or does it use JTar internally or something else?

Please, please *don't* post guessing or speculation replies - I have done *lots* of guessing and speculation already, and I have experimented to rule-out some possibilities. For instance, I renamed the OS-X "tar" and "bsdtar" executables, but Maven could still do the assembly-phase so I surmised Maven probably wasn't calling-out to the OS tar utility in "/usr/bin".

Ergo, as a last-ditch I'm hoping someone who knows can give me a solid, definitive answer; but no answer is better than a dozen guesses.

Why I'm asking is not important and will just make people post tangential 'answers' that don't answer the question. I just can't find a definitive answer in the Maven documentation or on any of the forums.

Also, I do *not* need to know how to make tar or gzip files using Maven. I *know* how to tell Maven to do that. What I don't know is how Maven is *internally implemented* to generate Tar file format(s), and I need to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the creation of the TAR file is not done with Linux TAR utility. It is done by the code itself, using [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/).

To create a TAR file, you would use the `maven-assembly-plugin` with the `tar` format. This plugin delegates the creation of archives to `plexus-archiver`, which itself uses Apache Commons Compress to create archives. This library implements a whole API for working with archives and it does not rely on the OS utilities.

Note that this is not specific to TAR file. This is also true for other types of archive, like ZIP.

Relevant source code:

- [`maven-assembly-plugin` asks for the archive to be created](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-assembly-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/assembly/mojos/AbstractAssemblyMojo.java#L504-L505)
- In case of a `tar` file, [the creation of a TAR archiver is made](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-assembly-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/assembly/archive/DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java#L294-L297)
- An instance of [`TarArchiver`](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-archiver/blob/b174ef5d935c94fe58da2b48913fde1f2b972a97/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/tar/TarArchiver.java) is returned by `plexus-archiver`
- The data is written using [`TarArchiveOutputStream`](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-archiver/blob/b174ef5d935c94fe58da2b48913fde1f2b972a97/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/tar/TarArchiver.java#L135-L136) from [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveOutputStream.html). This class is responsible for writing the byte data into the file.

Comment: Thanks Tunaki, that's exactly what I was looking for. This came from a problem on a Mac OS-X 10.10.5/Maven-3.3.3, only successfully Assembling with "<tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>" in the master pom. The OS-X 10.9 Macs don't need it, so its not a valid solution. I down-rev'd Maven to versions 'successfully' Assembling on other Macs, but no joy: Hence the question about where Maven gets it's Tar'ing functionality from. I'll look at the Plexus and Archiver versions, see if that's where the problem is coming from, and update the thread.

Comment: @CelticPoet It looks like there might another problem with your Maven setup then. You should create another question instead of editing this one. Also, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer if it best answered your question.

Comment: Certainly I've accepted the answer, with my thanks. At this moment I'll hold-off opening another question as I'm pretty certain the replies will just be superficial non-answers that just trot-out for 'answers' the very things I've already done ... that'd only be sort-of annoying just at the moment. Thanks again for your excellent response.